# How to extract functions from PHP source code with its usage in PHP

Tags: php, function, parsing, methods, reflection

I am looking for some library or class in PHP or Linux to extract all functions/methods from PHP source code along with its usage in project files.

I have used PHP ReflectionMethod and ReflectionClass but these libraries will return basic details without its usage details.

Example for ReflectionMethod:

```
    $classString = (string)$classNode->namespacedName;
    $de = new \ReflectionMethod($classString, 'testAction');
    echo $de->getName() . ' - ' . $de->getStartLine();
```

I do not see any method which can return its usage from files or a complete directory.

Please let me know if you need any other details.

Comment: i think you need to rollout your own code. With PHP [dir](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.dir.php) and [file](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.filesystem.php) functions ..  PHP somewhere had a parser function somewhere which you could also use to generate token from PHP source code

Comment: Found it it is within the [tokenizer](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.tokenizer.php).. Combine the three API's you should get pretty far into getting a source code scanner.

Comment: Hi @RaymondNijland by ReflectionClass and ReflectionMethod i can get all details of the file along with class, methods and properties etc. which I think tokenizer will do but in a very basic level. But I actually wanted to find a usage of a specific class method in a complete project.

Comment: yes i understood what you where looking for, you will need to program your own class or PHP library doing this